# MYSQL date in views not working

Tags: views, 7

I am connecting views to an external database and everything works fine if my views handler is a string but not as a date, here is my view definition:

```
$data['Punches']['Punch_Date'] = array(
   'title' => t('Punch Date'),
    'help' => t('Employees Punch Date'),
    'field' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_field_date',
      'click sortable' => TRUE,
    ),
    'sort' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_sort_date',
    ),
    'filter' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_filter_date',
    ),
    'argument' => array(
      'handler' => 'views_handler_argument_date',
    ),
  );
```

If I change views_handler_field_date to views_handler_field I can see the records in my view. The date coming from mysql looks like

```
2013-08-27
```

I would also like to format that date to look like

```
08-27-2013
```

The biggest problem is that I want to be able to filter between dates, thanks for any help that can be given.

Answer (score 0):

To set the date format used when dates are displayed on your site, navigate to `Home » Administration » Configuration » Regional and language`, and set date format.

Comment: That's if the format is already coming over in the unix format. I decided to just send a unix timestamp to the database to circumvent this, but thanks for the reply.